# Load List View when internet is not available

Tags: android, listview

In my application, I have a list view which uses ImageLoader in its adapter to load the images with lsit view items.

In the oncreate of the activity I fetch some URLS for the list view items like this :

```
private void fetchImages() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //fetching the list
        mCustomProgressDialog = CustomProgressDialog.createDialog(Group_SharePictureMainActivity.this, "", "");
        mCustomProgressDialog.show();
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                APIVariables apiVariables = new APIVariables();
                String getGroupImagesURL = apiVariables.getGroupImages(GroupsActivity.Group_ID);
                groupImages = ParseValues.getGroupImages(getGroupImagesURL);
                handlerFetchGroupImages.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        }.start();

    }
```

Here my problem is - I want to implement a situation, in which when Internet connection is not available , then the already generated list view ( when the internet was available) should come.

Is this possible to maintain the previous state of the list view when the network connection is not available ??

Thanks

Comment: You will have to use persistance

Comment: yes, it is possible, you can use chache to store Images, or you can also store images in your internal memory.

Comment: But my URLS are generated at run time. Then ?

Comment: You need to store URLS in internal database, when there is no internet connection, same URLS can be used to load the cache images.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you display images from server in a listview. You can cache images and load it when internet connection is off.

Lazy Loading of images. https://github.com/thest1/LazyList. It uses caching.

```
imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
```

In getview of your Custom List adapter

```
 ImageView image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
 imageLoader.DisplayImage("url", image);
```

In the ImageLoader Class of LazyLoading.

```
public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    System.out.println("Url................."+url);
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);//check if bitmap is there in cache. url is the key
    if(bitmap!=null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);//display if it is present.
    else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView); //cache and display image.
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);//display a dummy image until image is dowloaded and displayed.
    }
}
```

There is also an open source universal image loader. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader. Asynchronously display images. Uses caching.

Other ways of caching bitmaps. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: But my URLS are generated at run time. Then ?

Comment: i have used lazy loading by parsing json at runtime to get imageurls and display the same in listveiw.

Comment: MY QUESTION IS HOW WILL YOU PARSE THE DATA WHEN INTERNET IS NOT AVAILABLE THEN??????? THIS IS MY QUESTION. tHAT IS WHY I AM ASKING HOW TO MAINTAIN THE PREVIOUS STATE OF THE LISTVIEW

Comment: You need internet atleast the first time to download  and cache images. Then from the next time you can display image from cache memory when there is no internet.

Comment: you can store your urls or any other data that you have previously loaded in sqllite database and store Images in Internal meory or cache and load image from that urls that are stored in db

Answer (score 0):

You could use **LRUCache class** for caching the images downloaded in the application memory. When there is no internet, you could use the cached images to display in the listView. if there is internet, you could fetch new images and if the old images are no longer required clear the cache before you start downloading the new ones.

more about caching the images is described very well at this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html). 
you could use the sample application provided at that page.

Also, check out [this](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList).

Comment: But my URLS are generated at run time. Then ?

Comment: when u cache an image using the above technique, you store the URL from which it was downloaded as well. Its just like a key value pair. In the sample application, the URL's are predefined. But, you could generate the URL's at run time and just pass that to the ImageAdapter to cache and load images. the next time when u open the application, if the image is already present in the cache it will not download, just loads it from the cache even when there is no internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach:

When the internet connection is available download and store the image in internal Memory. If you want to store some other details you can also store that in SQLite database. If network is not available then fetch the values and images from database and memory respectively and load inside the list view.